# Python print without unicode character

Tags: python, unicode

How can I get rid of the unicode character `u` when printing. I am using python-2.6.6. Using command :

```
pprint(complexdict["key1"][n]["subkey"][0].values())
```

and it prints something like the follwing   :

```
[u'/data/dirA/myDir/NameofTheFile_1.tgz']
[u'/data/dirA/myDir/NameofTheFile_2.tgz']
[u'/data/dirA/myDir/NameofTheFile_3.tgz']
```

I am looking for a print out like this ( stripping out `[u'` and `]` ) :

```
/data/dirA/myDir/NameofTheFile_1.tgz
/data/dirA/myDir/NameofTheFile_2.tgz
/data/dirA/myDir/NameofTheFile_3.tgz
```

Thanks for any suggestions...

EDIT....

With the following, it works...

```
print complexdict["key1"][n]["subkey"][0].values()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

`dict.values()` returns a list of values ... in this case there is only one so its

```
print complexdict["key1"][n]["subkey"][0].values()[0] #get first value ...
```

you can see this easily as

```
>>> some_item = [u'/data/dirA/myDir/NameofTheFile_1.tgz']
>>> print some_item
[u'/data/dirA/myDir/NameofTheFile_1.tgz']
>>> print some_item[0]
/data/dirA/myDir/NameofTheFile_1.tgz
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still has the unicode character `u` and the two quotes at the end...

Comment: See my edit... With print it gives me the output as expected... +1 after your edit with `print`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a list(*), with something of your choosing between the items, you would use join. Also, for printing stuff out normally, you would probably use print rather than pprint.

The newline character is `\n`. You might use something like:

```
print "\n".join(complexdict["key1"][n]["subkey"][0].values())
```

(*) `complexdict["key1"][n]["subkey"][0]` is presumably a dict, so `complexdict["key1"][n]["subkey"][0].values()` will return a list.

Comment: If you know that `.values()` will return a list of exactly one value, you can add `[0]` to the end - get the first item in the list. I thought it was returning 3 values, and you wanted one on each line. Looking at it now, it's clear that your example output was from 3 separate pprints.